# FOSRestBundle custom view handler not registering

Tags: rest, symfony, csv, fosrestbundle, viewhandler

I'm trying to create custom handler for serializing response into csv format.

So far I've been following the steps from documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#custom-handler), however when calling my endpoint with .csv extension I still get the error:

`The format "csv" is not supported for serialization.`

Here's my `services.yml` config bit:

```
api.csv_handler:
    class: ApiBundle\ViewHandlers\CsvViewHandler

api.view_handler:
    parent: fos_rest.view_handler.default
    calls:
        - ["registerHandler", ["csv", ["@api.csv_handler", "createResponse"]]]
```

and in `config.yml`, under `fos_rest` I have this:

```
view:
    mime_types: { 'csv': ['text/csv','text/plain'] }
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        json: true
        xml:  true
        csv:  true
    templating_formats:
        html: true
format_listener:
    enabled: true
    rules:
        - { path: ^/, priorities: [ json, xml, csv ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
        - { path: ^/api/doc, priorities: [ html ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
```

The `createResponse` method inside my `CsvViewHandler` class currently only contains some debug code to verify if it's working, which it isn't.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you solve this problem?

Comment: I abandoned the idea

Answer (score 5):

You have to register your view handler in FOSRest bundle configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    ...
    service:
        view_handler: my_bundle.view_handler
    ...



services:
    ...
    my_bundle.my_handler:
        class: MyBundle\View\MyHandler
    my_bundle.view_handler:
        parent: fos_rest.view_handler.default
        calls:
            - ['registerHandler', [ 'my_format', ["@my_bundle.my_handler", 'createResponse'] ] ]
    ...
```

Comment: There is also example of usage in the bundle itself: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/e01be8113d4451adb3cbb29d7d2cc96bbc698179/Resources/doc/examples/RssHandler.php